# There is a way to pass a action via props? To make re-usable components with react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I would like to make a component that loads actions and states dynamically so that I can reuse it in other parts of the code.

**I'm trying this way but the action is firing before sending to component:**

```
function ClientsHeader(props) {
    const action = Actions.searchClients();
    return (
        <SearchHeader data={data} campoPesquisa={campoPesquisa} action={action}/>
    );
}    
export default ClientsHeader;
```

**On children:**

```
function SearchHeader(props) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const action = props.action;

  return;
  <div className="flex flex-1 w-full items-center justify-between">
    <Input
      placeholder="Search"
      onChange={event => dispatch(action(event))}
    />
  </div>;
}
```

**There is a way to call a function name with variables? Because that would solve this.**

Please don't be rude to my stupidity, I'm new to this :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is from the line `const action = Actions.searchClients();`

This actually calls the function `searchClients`.

It should rather be `const action = () => Actions.searchClients();`

Comment: The way you said, it has any difference than this way?
const action = Actions.searchClients;

Comment: Yhup... What you have is a **function call** while the other is a *function* ...


it is the same as writing `const action = function() { Actions.searchClients(); }`

Comment: @DaniloCunha If this solves the issue, kindly accept is as the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are calling Actions.searchClients in ClientsHeader component, you just need to pass the reference as

```
const action = Actions.searchClients;
```

Note: I think you should import the action in the component directly,

Hope it helps

Comment: It does help! Thanks :)